# saving image into database which is generated dynamically and saved in image button

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, image, qr-code

```
 Random rd = new Random();

            string data = rd.Next(111111111, 999999999).ToString();

            QRCodeGenerator q = new QRCodeGenerator();

            QRCodeGenerator.QRCode qc = q.CreateQrCode(data,

            QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q); 
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bm = qc.GetGraphic(28);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bm.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            byte[] b = ms.ToArray();
            Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," +                                                                              `Convert.ToBase64String(b);`
            String qr = Image1.ImageUrl.ToString();
```

i have generated qr code and put into imagebox i need to save it to sql database in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want to save the actual image in the db, just the link to it:

```
        Random rd = new Random();
        string Path="D:\data\images\"; //folder where you want to store images
        string data = rd.Next(111111111, 999999999).ToString();
        QRCodeGenerator q = new QRCodeGenerator();
        QRCodeGenerator.QRCode qc = q.CreateQrCode(data,
        QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q); 
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bm = qc.GetGraphic(28);
        Guid uniqueid=new Guid();
        bm.Save(path+uniqueid.ToString()+'.png', System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

You only save the link to this file in the DB
(the path and the file name to this png file) as well as an identifier that you will query to get this link.

You need to create a table in the database, add the fields needed 
(once you do this I could help you further with inserting the record in the db)

Answer (score 0):

First create a database in SQL, like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE QRDataBaseEntities
GO
CREATE TABLE Photo
(
    PhotoID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(100),
    Photo VARBINARY(MAX)
)
```

Then create a function in C#, like this:

```
void SaveOnDatabase()
{
        QRDataBaseEntities DbContext = new QRDataBaseEntities();
        Photo Item = new Photo();
        Item.Name = Image1;
        Item.Photo=b;

        DbContext.Photos.Add(Item);
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```